# VS Macro/Add-in to convert string concatenations to string.format style

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, string, add-in, visual-studio-macros

I have project in development where string operations like "Hi " + variable + ", welcome to Project" are used at many places (given example is very minor one).

One of the requirement is to convert it to string.format style.

It is very long and tedious job, where I would not like to break earlier working code due to any human error might happen while converting it.

I would like to if any Macro or VS command which I can create to handle it. Just like we mark block of code and do Extract function in Re-factor options.

Comment: Your question is? I am sure that no one is going to write the complete command for you :) Analyse the problem and break it up to manageable pieces

Comment: If not command, a pointer on how to create will help. But I was expecting something like this should already be there, as it is very generic.

Comment: provided the code below since you cannot access my blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt the code was a little long to post here, but I posted an answer at my blog: 
http://www.brianschmitt.com/2010/08/converting-concatenated-string-into.html

-- EDIT --
Per comment here is the relevant Macro - not sure why you cannot access...

```
Public Sub ConvertToStringFormat()
    DTE.UndoContext.Open("ConvertToStringFormat")
    Dim textSelection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Dim output As String = "string.Format(""{0}"", {1})"
    Dim delimt As String = ", "
    Dim fmtdTostring As String = ".tostring("""

    Dim txtSelection As String() = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(textSelection.Text.Trim, "\+\s_[+\n\r\t]|&\s_[+\n\r\t]|\+|&")
    Dim hardStrings As String = String.Empty
    Dim valueStrings As String = String.Empty
    Dim counter As Int16 = 0

    For Each str As String In txtSelection
        Dim tmpString As String = str.Trim
        If tmpString.StartsWith("""") Then
            hardStrings &= tmpString.Substring(1, tmpString.Length - 2)
        Else
            Dim fmt As String = String.Empty
            Dim indxToString As Int32 = 0

            If tmpString.ToLower.Contains(fmtdTostring) Then
                indxToString = tmpString.ToLower.IndexOf(fmtdTostring)
                fmt = tmpString.Substring(indxToString + 11, tmpString.Length - tmpString.ToLower.IndexOf(""")", indxToString) - 1)
            End If

            If fmt <> String.Empty Then
                hardStrings &= "{" & counter.ToString & ":" & fmt & "}"
                valueStrings &= tmpString.Substring(0, indxToString) & delimt
            Else
                hardStrings &= "{" & counter.ToString & "}"
                valueStrings &= tmpString & delimt
            End If

            counter += 1
        End If
    Next

    If valueStrings <> String.Empty Then valueStrings = valueStrings.Substring(0, valueStrings.Length - delimt.Length)

    textSelection.Text = String.Format(output, hardStrings, valueStrings)
    DTE.UndoContext.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: above link is not working, looks like all pages in your site are serving a blank gif file. This might be related to HTTPHandler.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Looks like you have put lot of efforts in it, will give it a try and let you know.